# How to fix the looping from my catch exception? it is looping with the number of attempts instead of looping back to my scanner input

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

How to fix the looping from my catch exception? it is looping with the number of attempts instead of looping back to my scanner input.

I'm trying to make a number guessing game in java with for loop and try catch to execute exceptions. But the problem is the exception syso keeps on looping itself.

Here is my attempt:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        int cor = 1 + (int)(50 * Math.random());
        int attempts = 20;  
        System.out.println("enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.");
        for (int i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {            
            try {
                int ans = sc.nextInt();
                if (ans == cor) {
                    System.out.println("You got it for "+ i +" attempts.");
                    break;
                } else if (ans > 50) {
                    System.err.println("Out of range.");
                    System.out.println("Enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.");
                } else if (ans < 0) {
                    System.err.println("Out of range.");
                    System.out.println("Enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.");
                } else if(ans < cor) {
                    System.out.println("Too low. try again.");
                } else if (ans > cor) {
                    System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
                }
            } catch(Exception r) {
                System.err.println("Invalid");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code output shows like this:

```
enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.
2
Too low. try again.
60
Enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.
Out of range.
23
Too high. Try again.
-20
Out of range.
Enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.
32
Too high. Try again.
a
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
Invalid
```

Comment: Your nextInt call fails because the next token in the input stream cannot be converted to integer.  The next token in the input stream continues to be the next token in the input stream until you explicitly consume it.  Put a call to nextLine in the exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting. As someone commented, it does that, because the token is never consumed. I ran a debugger on it, and I can see it step through just fine until you enter in a wrong type. Then for said reason it stops asking for input and automatically go's to the catch each loop because the token hasn't been consumed.

I did write something that works though.
First I changed your 'for' loop to a 'while' loop.

Next I broke your input validation into it's own method. 'validateGuess'.
Here I consolidated two of your if statements to a single statement. Once it's validated, it'll to be compared against the answer.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cor = 1 + (int) (50 * Math.random());
    int attempts = 20;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("enter the number to guess from 1 - 50.");

    while (i < attempts) {

        int guess = validateGuess(sc);

        if (guess != -1) {
            if (guess == cor) {
                System.out.println("You got it for " + i + " attempts.");
                break;
            } else if (guess < cor) {
                System.out.println("Too low. try again.");
            } else if (guess > cor) {
                System.out.println("Too high. Try again.");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

private static int validateGuess(Scanner scanner) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    try {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
        if (i >= 1 && i <= 50) {
            return i;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Please try again. (1-50)");
        }
    }catch (InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException e) {
        if (input.equals("q")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Please try again. (1-50)");
    }
    return -1;
}
```